# Declare pointered struct at build time

Tags: c, linux, gcc

This is how I can initialize a struct with pointers at build time.

```
struct example_struct {
    int count;
    int *values;
};

int i1[] = { 1, 2 };
int i2[] = { 10, 20, 30 };

struct example_struct items[] = {
    { .count = 2, .values = &i1[0] },
    { .count = 3, .values = &i2[0] },
    { .count = 0, .values = NULL },
};
```

The actual situation I am facing is quite lengthy and more complex than this example.
Therefore I am looking for a way to circumvent extra declaration of the arrays. Instead I would like to directly note the arrays in place,
that means convert `.values = &i1[0]` into something like `.values = { 1, 2 }` (which unfortunately is invalid syntax for gcc).

Does a solution exist for this?

To be clear, I know this example could be changed to

```
items[] = {
    2,   1, 2,
    3,   10, 20, 30
};
```

and reading values in a different way. But my case really requires pointers to elements that normally are read at runtime from variable configurations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use compound literals. Research the lifetime of compound literals to make sure they will be valid upon use.

```
.values = (int[]){1, 2}
```

Maybe I am thinking ahead of myself, but your code example could look like:

```
#define ITEM(...)  { \
         .count = sizeof((int[]){__VA_ARGS__})/sizeof(int), \
         .values = (int[]){__VA_ARGS__}, \
     }

struct example_struct items[] = {
    ITEM(1, 2),
    ITEM(10, 20, 30),
    {0},
};
```

Comment: Wow that was fast and I feel a little ashamed for this simple thing was not among all weird notations that I have tried. Thanks a lot! Your second example is appreciated too.